# Invalid object name "playerData"

Tags: c#, sql

in my database i have a table "playerData", but it can't be found, any idea why?

```
public Form1()
{
       InitializeComponent();
}
public static string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\lupul\Documents\players.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        //

        private static void Init()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\jogadoras.txt");
            string sir;
            char[] split = { '-' };
            conn.Open();
            while ((sir = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] siruri = sir.Split(split);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO playerData(PlayerName) VALUES (@name)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", siruri[0].Trim());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Initializarea a fost realizata țavă", "powerr softu lu mură", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Im trying to insert from a .txt file into the database, and this error pops up:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name
> 'playerData'.'

jogadoras.txt:

```
Jose Andrea
Popescu Matthew
Morman Maria
```

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRokW.png)

I tried moving the table around, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you specify the database in your connection string? Also, does the user have permissions to access the table?

Comment: Side note: connection and comand objects need `using` to dispose them. Considert using `SqlBulkCopy` for much faster inserts.

Comment: i donyt know what you mean, i have updated the code in the post

Comment: The error says there's no table `playerData` in the database. You didn't specify the database name in the connection string (using `Initial Catalog`) so your code is actually trying to find the table in `master`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Specify the Database, you are looking into MASTER!